# REGEX Валидация строки с пробелами и литерами

Tags: javascript

Не могу написать регулярное выражение что бы полностью провалидировать входящую строку согласно требованиям:

Латиница верхний нижний регистр ([A-Za-z])
Цифры,
Пробел,
Минимум -2 позиции(не считая пробелов).
Не разрешается только цифры. Необходима хотя бы одна буква. Только буквы - разрешается
Пример разрешения : асs, a a, a1, a 1, asas  asas12
Не разрешается: 1111, q, qqqq@#, @@@aaaa, asas1212$

Максимально продвинулся до:  ^\s*([a-z\d]\s*){2,}$
Но не могу регулировать количество символов.
Спасибо

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/u2Fsyl/1

Comment: @ splash58  
Спасибо за решение. Работает почти все.
Не могу понять почему не проходит "p1" и "p  1".
А вот "1p"  или "1  p"    - проходят.
Еще раз спасибо

Comment: ничего не менял - https://regex101.com/r/u2Fsyl/2

Comment: @ splash58
"a1" или "a 1" или "a 12345" не работает

Answer (score 0):

вот так вот `/^[A-z\s][A-z\d\s]+$/`

Comment: Спасибо, но есть проблема.
Пробелы принимаются, но они не считаются как символы.
Валидатор не должен пропустить, например, "а   "( а и пробел)  или "    " (три пробела)
Возможно : "а в", "а      Б", "а    1"

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?!.*(.)\1{3,})(?=.*[a-z])[a-z\d](\s*[a-z\d])+$
```

Первая группа `^(?!.*(.)\1{3,})` проверяет что нет 4 или больше повторов одного символа подряд

Вторая `(?=.*[a-z])` - что присутствует буква

[Подробнее](https://regex101.com/r/u2Fsyl/3)

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Работает!!